# Preload AdMob interstitials across activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, admob, ads

I've tried a ton of stuff using static variables, but I can't seem to find a way to preload an interstitial ad on one activity (my game) and then show it on the next (my score screen) Anybody know a way to do this?

I kept getting nullpointerexceptions using static variables, so I'm guessing that that does not work for some garbage collector reason, perhaps they are removed when the activity is destroyed (I use system.exit to exit the game activity to keep the game working properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh wow, lots of problems here. Let's go from biggest to smallest.

1. Do **NOT** use System.exit(). This will attempt to exit the VM, killing your app as well as your Activity. If your Activity needs this in order to cleanup then you have some serious problems with your Activity.
2. Do **NOT** use static variables unless you understand how to use them. And **definitely do NOT** use them to try to transfer data between Activities.

I think the solution you are looking for is to to craft your game and score screens as fragments and show them both within the one Activity.